# New Schema.describeSObjects not working as expected

Tags: apex, describesobject

There is a new method for Schema in Winter 14 called [Schema.describeSObjects](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Schema_describeSObjects.htm). The idea as I understand the docs is that you can pass in a list of sObject names as strings, and get back the describe results for each of them in a list of results. But it doesn't seem to working as I would expect, but maybe I am just missing something obvious...

As I understand it, these calls should return the same information. The new method returns the basic info, but when I request the recordtypeinfo, I get back null...

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = Account.sObjectType.getDescribe();
system.debug(r); //Returns basic describe info 
system.debug(r.getRecordTypeInfosByName()); //Returns all the record types

String[] types = new String[]{'Account'};
List<Schema.DescribeSobjectResult> results = Schema.describeSObjects(types);
system.debug(results); //Returns the same basic describe info
system.debug(results[0].getRecordTypeInfosByName()); //**returns null**
```

Comment: Not sure what is going on there. Oddly, `.getRecordTypeInfos()` seems to work fine. You could use that to rebuild the Map if required.

Comment: That is unexpected, both `getRecordTypeInfosById()` and `getRecordTypeInfosByName()` doesn't work but `getRecordTypeInfos` does. There is nothing seems to be missed in sample code.

Comment: Yep, most odd, i performed the same checks as @reddev and scanned the docs for any hint of a limitation comment and found nothing, thus concluding.... you've found a platform bug. I'd also agree with Daniel about the workaround in the meantime.

Comment: Ok - thanks to everyone for the sanity check - let me see what Developer Support has to say on this issue..

Comment: Heard back from dev support...they ran our code and confirmed we are right...and offered Daniel's solution as the workaround...I'll update again in support hears more from R&D

Comment: @BritishBoyinDc or Daniel Ballinger, would one of you please create an answer so that future visitors don't have to read this whole comment thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So support confirmed that this was happening, but I don't see it in Known Issues, so I guess it it a limitation for now - I'll raise an idea and see what happens. For now though, you can follow [Daniel's](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/102/daniel-ballinger) suggestion and build your own map:

```
String[] types = new String[]{'Account'};
List<Schema.DescribeSobjectResult> results = Schema.describeSObjects(types);
Map<String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rmap = new Map<String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> ();

for (Schema.RecordTypeInfo ri: results[0].getRecordTypeInfos()) {
        rmap.put(ri.getname(), ri);//use ri.getRecordTypeId() for an Id map 
    }
```

Comment: Here's the link to the Known Issue:
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T1zGAAS